# What's the correct way to implement dependency inversion with single-method interfaces in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, dependency-inversion

I'm implementing Clean Architecture so I'm using [use cases](https://nanosoft.co.za/blog/post/clean-architecture-use-cases). Let's say:

```dart
abstract interface class UploadAssetUseCase{
  Future<(AssetUploadFailure?, Url?)> execute(Uint8List data);
}
```

For this interface, Dart analyzer throws this warning:

> Unnecessary use of an abstract class. Try making 'execute' a top-level
> function and removing the class.

Because of that, I switched to this approach:

```dart
typedef UploadAssetUseCase=  Future<(AssetUploadFailure?, Url?)> Function(Uint8List data);
```

This actually makes sense and is kind of testable (I need to create an extra abstract class for mocking it).

The problem comes when I try to implement this.

```dart
class FirebaseStorageUploadAssetUseCase implements UploadAssetUseCase{
  
}
```

This, obviously, throws an Exception since `UploadAssetUseCase`is a Function, so it can't be implemented. To implement it, I need to create a class to be implemented instead of the Function itself, leading to the very same warning that I mentioned before:

```dart
abstract interface class _IUploadAssedUseCase {//Getting the warning that I was trying to avoid
  Future<(AssetUploadFailure?, Url?)> call(
    Uint8List document,
  );
}

class FirebaseStorageUploadAssetUseCase implements _IUploadAssedUseCase{
  const FirebaseStorageUploadAssetUseCase(this.storage);
  final FirebaseStorage storage;

  @override
  Future<(AssetUploadFailure?, Url?)> call(
    Uint8List document,
  ){
   
  }
}
```

So, in this context, what's the best approach for this? Should I just ignore the warning and keep using classes instead of top-level Functions? Is there any other way to do this that I'm not aware of?

I'm using analysis options 3.1.0 with this configuration (if you guys want to replicate):

```yaml
analyzer:
  errors:
    invalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member: error
    const_eval_throws_exception: ignore
linter:
  rules:
    public_member_api_docs: false
    library_private_types_in_public_api: false
    lines_longer_than_80_chars: false
```

Comment: I added the same code no warnings on my side try updating flutter to latest. Your first approach is a good approach try studying S.O.I.L.D principles as well

Comment: I get no warnings using your code. I use Android Studio. Maybe check if the Flutter and Dart plugins are up to date?

Comment: I'm using analysis options, maybe that's why you don't get it (yeah, both Flutter and Dart are up to date)
@Ivo

Comment: Why would you  need to use `implements` at all?  Just create a function with the same signature; it's already substitutable wherever `UploadAssetUseCase` is expected.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for your feedback!
I considered it and you're right, but it's important to me that the implementation is placed inside a class, because I need to inject into this class whatever instance I need to make its methods testable (for example, FirebaseStorage instance, but could be any other usecase, datasource or client). This is not possible (as far as I know) with functions, cause I'd need to modify the parameters received by the Function and it wouldn't fulfill the signature requirements

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this warning, you can add an empty constructor to your abstract class.

```dart
abstract interface class _IUploadAssedUseCase {
  _IUploadAssedUseCase();
  //Getting the warning that I was trying to avoid
  Future<(AssetUploadFailure?, Url?)> call(
    Uint8List document,
  );
}
```

Comment: yeah it's kind of a workaround. I can also add the comment to ignore it, but I want to achieve something that does not look like a workaround, but as a real solution

Comment: I think that this warning is not designed to stop you from doing this  kinds of things. It's like the warning on discarded futures when you are using a futureBuilder. I don't see any  other way of doing it properly

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts bro. Me neither, I find my first approach as the best way to do it, instead of using Functions

Comment: To get back to my solution, I don't really think it's a workaround because by expliciting a constructor, you tell the linter that you do want the abstract class to behave like a class that will be overriden and not only by something replaceable by typdef. So imo that could be a proper solution

Comment: I didn't think about that. I think you're right